# Quartz cron expression in Mule 3 - Can it be made dynamic?

Tags: mule

Can the cron expression in the Quartz endpoint be made dynamic?

I tried configuring my endpoint as follows:

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="trigger"
        cronExpression="#[app.registry.abc.cronEx]"
        repeatInterval="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

where abc is a spring bean.

But it throws an exception when the application starts:

```
10/04/12 16:49:27.955 ERROR [main] DefaultMuleApplication - null
java.text.ParseException: Unexpected character: #
at org.quartz.CronExpression.storeExpressionVals(CronExpression.java:642)
at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:430)
at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:255)
at org.quartz.CronTrigger.setCronExpression(CronTrigger.java:474)
at org.mule.transport.quartz.QuartzMessageReceiver.doStart(QuartzMessageReceiver.java:125)
at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageHandler$3.onTransition(AbstractTransportMessageHandler.java:316)
at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
at org.mule.transport.ConnectableLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ConnectableLifecycleManager.java:51)
```

...

Is there any way of acheiving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Spring Expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based):

```
cronExpression="#{abc.cronEx}"
```

Comment: I tried running the application, default values are read and application was up and running. Now when i change the values at run time, cron expression is not been updated still default values are read, any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: If you want to modify the values after Mule have started, you will have to use Mule's internal API to reconfigure (and potentially restart) the inbound endpoint.

Comment: Am not sure about the API. Can you please share some details on the API to be used and where exactly this API is to be called (in context logic or within a flow)

Comment: You have two potential entry points to Mule's internals: the MuleContext that gives you access to the Registry where everything is accessible (connectors...) or the MBeanServer where important internals are registering MBeans.